# How to calculate the average of elements in a stack of intergers

Tags: c#, algorithm, stack

I created a method "AverageOfStack()" receives as an input a stack of integers and returns the average of the
elements in the stack.
But I don't know how to make sure that, At the end of the algorithm, execution, the stack used as input must
remain in the same state (same elements and in the same order).

Here is what i tried:

`

```
  Stack<int> myStack = new Stack<int>();
            myStack.Push(5);
            myStack.Push(10);
            myStack.Push(20);
            myStack.Push(30);
            myStack.Push(40);

            Console.WriteLine("ELEMENT IN THE STACK");
            foreach (var item in myStack)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The Average of Stack:{0}",AverageOfStack(myStack));
        }

        public static double AverageOfStack(Stack<int> givenStack)
        {
            double average = 0;
            double sum = 0;
            while (givenStack.Count !=0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < givenStack.Count; i++)
                {
                    sum += givenStack.Pop();
                }
                average = sum / givenStack.Count;
            }
            while (givenStack.Count!=0)
            {
                givenStack.Reverse();
            }
            return average;
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, use [`Enumerable.Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=net-7.0) which doesn't modify the stack:

```
Console.WriteLine("The Average of Stack:{0}", myStack.Average());
```

The elements and order stays same:

```
ELEMENT IN THE STACK
40
30
20
10
5
The Average of Stack:21
```

If you want to know how `Stack<T>` ensures that it doesn't get modifed during enumeration, you could look at [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,f504f9346dc9c3e9,references).

But you can also do it manually with a `foreach`(which is as safe as `Average`):

```
int total = 0;
foreach(int i in myStack)
{
    total += i;
}
int average = total / myStack.Count; // 21
```

Comment: What Tim is saying is correct, you will need to add Using System.Linq on top of your code and you will get the Average method (and more).